# Android In-app Billing, how confirm that product was downloaded

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I trying use Dungeons example in my app. In Android development guide it's written that I should confirm delivery product to user sending CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS to market, but I don't see it in example or am I wrong? Should I confirm download and my app should remember if content was successfully delivered?

Where is the best place to invoke downloading, in activity using AsyncTask, in ResponseHandler class or different?

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I've been wondering about today too. From what I can see, in the Dungeons example, when `BillingService#purchaseStateChanged` is called, it automatically acknowledges all notifications after verifying the purchases.

See lines 506-509 in the example BillingService.java:

```
if (!notifyList.isEmpty()) {
    String[] notifyIds = notifyList.toArray(new String[notifyList.size()]);
    confirmNotifications(startId, notifyIds);
}
```

The solution would appear to be relocating this logic to a place you can manually call when you have completed delivery of your content.

I'm planning to remove that code and make the `BillingService#confirmNotifications` public so I can call it from my `PurchaseObserver` implementation when I've delivered my content.

I'll update with the result, but it seems to be a good starting point.

Comment: I made `BillingService#confirmNotifications` public and I add two parameters `startId, notifyIds` to `PurchaseObserver#onPurchaseStateChange` and applications seems to work fine. I'll be testing it more shortly. So thank you for advice! If you have any other observation about downloading or confirming content delivery please share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope Following Code helps u.

```
@Override
    public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState, String itemId,
            int quantity, long purchaseTime, String developerPayload) {
        if (Consts.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPurchaseStateChange() itemId: " + itemId + " " + purchaseState);
        }

        if (developerPayload == null) {
            logProductActivity(itemId, purchaseState.toString());
        } else {
            logProductActivity(itemId, purchaseState + "\n\t" + developerPayload);
        }

        if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            mOwnedItems.add(itemId);

            Log.v("log_tag", "Item Purchased");

        }
        mCatalogAdapter.setOwnedItems(mOwnedItems);
        mOwnedItemsCursor.requery();
    }
```

In Log if you  get "Item Purchased" it indicates that you have successfully download the Item.

Comment: Thanks, I know this code. I don't know how to commit product delivery, because something could go wrong while downloading.